# Read PowerBI tables from Excel

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a PowerBI file connected to a server so I get there all the information and I have some filters to get part of that information to send to another people.

I need to read the filtered table in Excel in a friendly way (I only could use the export data menu, but it prints an awful .csv file and I have to make a text to column and then give the table some format)

Is there any way to link a table in Excel to anoter table in PowerBI, and update the table in Excel and have the updated (and filtered, as shown in PowerBI) information? Or maybe creating a script in PowerBI that exports the data in a nice format?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correct, you wants to export your report's underlying/summarize data to excel in some good format. If this is the case, you have multiple option to export your data. You can see the details of different options beautifully explained [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0a4tKrakZiE) in the video tutorial and hope you will find your best match case in this tutorial.